# Probability of each state less than or equal to $2^{-n}$ for each $n$?

Tags: probability-theory

This relates to the hint to exercise 3.6.5 in Rosenthal's *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory*. ($\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P$) is a probability triple, where:

1. $\Omega$ is countable (in this book, that also includes finite - cf. p. 200)
2. $\mathscr{F} = 2^{\Omega}$

The hint says that "for each $\omega \in \Omega$ and each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $P(\{\omega\}) \le 1 / 2^n$." But I must be interpreting something incorrectly, because the way I see it the hint isn't true:

Let $\Omega$ be just $\{1, 2\}$, $\mathscr{F}$ the powerset, and let $P(\{1\}) = 1, P(\{2\} = 0$. Then $\Omega$ is finite and hence countable, but it is not true that for each $n \in \mathbb{N},  P(\{1\}) \le 1 / 2^n$. It in fact isn't true for any natural number $n$. And in fact for any countable set, if you just assign probabilities uniformly to a finite subset and 0 to everything else, there will always be some $n$ large enough to make the hint incorrect for those states having nonzero probability.

The problem doesn't show up in the Errata I've found for the book, and it is assigned in several classes I've found, so I must be missing some implicit assumption. But neither I nor a friend with whom I'm working through the book can figure out what Rosenthal means here.

Comment: "The hint says that "for each $\omega \in \Omega$ and each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $P(\{\omega\}) \le 1 / 2^n$."" Not at all. The hint says to proceed by contradiction, that is, *to assume that some specific property Q holds*, then, to show that Q implies that $P(\{\omega\})\le1/2^n$ for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and every $n$, which is absurd hence Q never holds. The exercise is correct. What is Q already?

Comment: OK, so you're saying that the hint means: If we assume that there exists some sequence of independent events $A_1, A_2, ... \in \mathscr{F}$ such that $P(A_i) = 1/2$ for each i, *then* the statement of the hint would follow. That makes sense. Thanks!